# Are verb-like classes a code smell?

Tags: object-oriented, patterns-and-practices, code-smell, anti-patterns

I do a lot of flat-file processing to extract data. The file "formats" are very unique and each file format requires a lot of format-specific code. Sometimes, the parsing code needs to maintain a lot of state while the file is being read. I've used something like this "pattern" at times:

```
parser = New FileTypeAParser(filename)
parser.ParseEnterFile
data = parser.ParsedData
```

Or, consider a class that factors large numbers. For efficiency reason, upon being instantiated, the class would internally generate and cache list a primes. It would then be called many times with different numbers like this:

```
factors = factorizer.Factor(veryLargeNumber)
```

**Original Question**

The adage is *Class names should be nouns; method names should be verbs.* Is it a code smell to name and use classes in the way shown in the examples? If so, how do I refactor the examples to deodorize them and remove the code smell?

**Revised Question**

Based on the comments, I now realize that I *am* using nouns. After putting more thought into it, I realized that my concern is that these classes very verb-like in substance and in name. Is this something to be concerned about?

Comment: What are you talking about?  All of your class names are already nouns, not verbs.

Comment: I thought Parser and Factorizer (Factorer?) *were* nouns.

Comment: If your class were named FileTypeAParsing, then yes, I'd agree you should refactor it.  FileTypeAParser is a noun.  As to your more generic question, yes, you want to try and name your classes as a noun and your methods as verbs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see [Execution in the Kingdom of Nouns](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.de/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html) as the extreme version of what this question is about.

Comment: Even if you had verbs as *object* names, there's an overriding principle that *might* justify it. The name should match the abstraction provided. For example, a C++ object who's main purpose is to act like a function (the class overrides the `operator()` method) might be named with a verb. I can't imagine a case where the class should be named as a verb, but if it's possible, the same overriding principle should apply - the name should match the abstraction.

Comment: @Scottie - "Parsing" can be a noun too. Example - "The parsing was done quickly". Of course that doesn't mean it would be a good name for that class - the class would have to represent "the parsing" rather than "the parser" (a concurrent task abstraction?).

Comment: That's a noun?  Seems like a verb to me, but I didn't do that well in English...  If I were to say "the cutting was done quickly", cutting is a verb, right?

Comment: I just revised my question after thinking about why my underlying concern is.

Comment: @Scottie: No, in the sentence "the cutting was done quickly" "was done" is a verb and "the cutting" is a subject. The form "cutting" is also used as part of verb in progressive tense ("he is cutting"), but in this context it acts as noun.

Comment: @poke: If the class' name accurately describes the role/function of the class, then you don't need to be concerned that the class name is verb-like

Comment: @Scottie - if you can write "the <word>", then `<word>` can be a noun. However, that doesn't necessarily mean `<word>` is acting as a noun elsewhere - as Jan says, "parsing" can be the past-continuous form of "to parse". Actually, I think it's a general rule that verbs in past-continuous form can be used as nouns. In practice, "noun", "verb" etc describe roles of words relative to the grammar - English is pretty flexible about letting many words take on different roles. Nouns can be used as verbs, verbs can be used as nouns, adjectives can be used as nouns, etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not "verb like", it's a state. If you have a process with sufficiently complex state, where else would you put it if not in a class.

What might be a code smell is a class with methods that have to be called in particular order. A single `parse` method that will return the parsed data, it is easier to use than leaving the data in the object to be picked up by separate call. Of course provided the whole operation can be done in a single step no matter how complex.

Alternatively you could have the data class with a `parseFrom(File)` method (which would internally create appropriate parser class (which would be internal or even inner).